# Alert the ID from a jquery post

Tags: javascript, php

I have 3 dependent select lists that are populated form mysql and then I use jquery posts to populate the rest with on change events. Once the 3 list have a selection it outputs data about the combination of the three for example based on those specs it was last bought from this supplier at that price. I would like to echo an edit button with the id so that i can build a form using that id, however when I echo out the picture i cannot alert it using the class or the img attribute.

The PHP:

```
 echo "
    <div class='steel-edit-button'><img id='".$row['grade_id']."' src='pics/edit-paper.png' class='left-item-pic'></div>
    <div class='seller-base-info'>
        <div class='seller-info-header'><span class='dealer-title'>Supplier:</span><br>".$row['dealer']."</div>
        <div class='seller-price-contain'><span class='dealer-title'>Price:<br></span>".$row['price']." /<br>".$row['length']."</div>
        <div class='seller-date-contain'><span class='dealer-title'>Date:<br></span>".$row['date']."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='seller-comments'>Comments:<br><textarea class='seller-comments' disabled placeholder='".$row['comment']."'></textarea></div>

    ";
```

is what im echoing out and then this is the script:

```
$(".left-item-pic").click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Try `$('img[class="left-item-pic"]').click(function(){ });`

Comment: @Daan: Not a good idea. That's not going to work if `$('.left-item.pic')` didn't, and will fail in many cases where `$('.left-item.pic')` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely thing is that the script runs before the element exists, and so $(".left-item-pic")` doesn't find it, and the event handler never gets attached. Three options:

1. Put the script *after* the element in the HTML (the common recommendation is just before the closing `</body>` tag)
2. Use jQuery's [`ready` function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to schedule your script to run on "DOM ready"
3. Use a delegated handler instead:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", ".left-item-pic", function() {
       alert($(this).attr("id"));
   });
   ```

---

Side note: `$(this).attr("id")` can be simply `this.id`, the attribute is reflected as a property on the DOM element.

Comment: Thank you! this was killing me! you were right. Because the the script was before the item was displayed it didn't know were to look. just put it after the div and it worked perfectly!!!